# prop.test() in R assumptions?

Tags: r, proportion, normality-assumption

Can anyone verify if the following assumptions are true for prop.test in R?

I think it's a hypothesis test for differences in proportions between groups, no?

Key assumptions(?):

1. Samples are randomly drawn from each population
2. Samples are independently drawn from one another
3. Minimum sample size is 10
4. Samples must be drawn from a normal distribution? <- not sure about this one

Comment: In 1) and 2) $k\ge 2$ samples are assumed to be independent binomial, which means numbers of successes among independent Bernoulli trials. 4) A chi-squared test statistic is shown; test is essentially equiv. to chi-sq test on $2 \times k$ table of counts of successes and failures. For $k = 2,$ test is similar to approx normal tests of equality of binomial population proportions: $H_0: p_1=p_2$ vs. one or two-sided alternative. Thus in (3) one needs some such rule as $\min(n_ip_i, n_i(1-p_i)) > 5.$ For examples, search this site for 'test of binomial proportions.'